# #1 Parsing trouble java.lang.NumberFormatException in GSEA 4.2.1

Tags: gsea, parsing

I am getting the following error message when I tried to load .TXT data file to GSEA 4.2.1.  I tried different way to change the file name as .GCT but not working.  Any suggestion? Many thanks.

Full Error Message:

```
There were errors: ERROR(S) #:1
Parsing trouble
java.lang.NumberFormatException: ...

---- Stack Trace ----
# of exceptions: 1
------For input string: "description"------
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "description"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.AbstractParser.parseStringToFloat(AbstractParser.java:266)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.AbstractParser.parseFieldsIntoFloatArray(AbstractParser.java:371)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.AbstractParser.parseTextMatrixToDataset(AbstractParser.java:293)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.TxtDatasetParser.parse(TxtDatasetParser.java:109)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserFactory.readDatasetTXT(ParserFactory.java:201)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserFactory.read(ParserFactory.java:760)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserFactory.read(ParserFactory.java:737)
    at org.gsea_msigdb.gsea/edu.mit.broad.genome.parsers.ParserWorker.doInBackground(ParserWorker.java:52)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what was not correctly formatted? I followed the instruction on their manual .txt and am getting this same error. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response, if you do get chance @Hong please remember to "accept" your answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out the error. My .TXT was not correctly formated, following the instruction from [their manual](https://software.broadinstitute.org/cancer/software/gsea/wiki/index.php/Data_formats#Expression_Data_Formats) under .TXT format worked.